# Check if array of predefined size is populated - Pascal

Tags: arrays, size, conditional-statements, pascal, procedure

I'm doing some homework which defines how a procedure should be made, `procedure DoSort`.

The procedure has one local variable, called 'data', which is an array of 25 integers.
`data : array[0..24] of Integer;` The procedure has four main steps:

1) PopulateArray(data)
2) ShowNumbersInList(data)
3) PlotBars(data)
4) Sort(data)

These steps each are procedure calls to extra procedures. However, if I code it just like that, the array gets re-populated with different values on every call of `DoSort`. I need the array to be populated ONLY on the initial call. I've tried many things...

```
    if data[0] = data[1]
    if data[0] = nil
    if data[0].free
    if data.free
    if data = nil
```

etc. I need to do this without creating another variable, i.e. `firstRun : Boolean`. So basically, what I need to do is check if the array has been populated

```
    procedure DoSort();
    Var
      data : array[0..24] of Integer;
    begin
      if data[0] = data[1] then // DOESN'T WORK
      begin
        PopulateArray(data); 
      end
      else
      begin
        ShowNumbersInList(data);
        PlotBars(data);
        Sort(data);
      end;
    end;
```

This is driving me crazy, because I can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` array is local to your procedure `DoSort()`. This means that every time `DoSort()` is called, an uninitialized array is used. (allocated on the stack).

To persist the data, declare it outside the scope of your procedure and pass it by reference, `procedure DoSort(var data: array of integer);`.

Initialize your data before entering DoSort the first time only.

Example:

```
procedure Main;
var
  data : array[0..24] of Integer;
begin
  PopulateData(data);

  while jobNotDone do
  begin
    DoSort(data);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's been many many moons since I wrote any Pascal.  However, in other languages, I would create a singleton (Java, C++, etc) basically one would make the constructor PRIVATE, so you can only create a single instance through a call.

Since it IS homework, I'll not give you the complete answer, but the link below should get you started on a good path.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Singleton_Pattern#Simple_Singleton

Good luck, and hope you'll respond with the details.